# webdriver (c#) - How can I extend my method to allow for custom attributes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written (actually re-appropriated from the internet) the following block of code which allows me to wait until an elements' attribute contains specific text.  I have tested the code and it appears to work just fine (better approach welcome):

```
IWebElement element = Utility.driver.FindElement(By.Id("modal-exchange"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Utility.driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
wait.Until((d) =>
{
return element.GetAttribute("outerHTML").Contains("block");
});
```

I wrapped this code inside a method inside my Utility class so I can call it frequently.  For further convenience, I modified it slightly to allow me to specify any "By" locator when calling it from my classes:

```
public static void WaitOnAttributeChange(By by)
{

    IWebElement element = Utility.driver.FindElement(by);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Utility.driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    wait.Until((d) =>
    {
        return element.GetAttribute("outerHTML").Contains("block");
    });

}
```

Usage is as follows:

```
Utility.WaitOnAttribute(By.Id("modal-exchange"));
```

The issue I have now is that (again for convenience) I would like to take the same logic I applied to the By locator and apply it to .GetAttribute and .Contains so I can specify these in my classes should they change, or I'm looking for something other than "outerHTML" or "block"

I hope this makes sense as I'm not sure of the correct terminology I should be using to explain my question.  Edits to the title of my question also welcome

**UPDATE**

I have been able to get this working now by editing my method as follows:

```
public static void WaitOnAttribute(By by, string attribute, string text)
        {
            IWebElement element = Utility.driver.FindElement(by);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Utility.driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            wait.Until((d) =>
            {
                return element.GetAttribute(attribute).Contains(text);
            });

        }
```

And calling it as follows:

```
Utility.WaitOnAttribute(By.Id("modal-exchange"),"outerHTML", "block");
```

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly couldn't you just do `Utility.WaitOnAttribute(By.Id("modal-exchange"), "outerHTML", "block");` as an example and update the wrapped method to utilize those parameters?

Comment: Indeed, isn't it just a case of passing another string through as a parameter?

Comment: Thanks guys - programming is new to me but I was able to tinker and get this working following your suggestions.  I will update my OP to reflect what I have done